# Google Experiment with multi step shopping cart

Tags: google-analytics, a-b-testing

I am attempting to run an experiment that tests an alternate checkout UI. For the experiment, I use the URL of the original checkout and the URL of the alternate checkout as a variation. Google validates the experiment; however, when the experiment is running, a user can never get past the first step of the checkout  when the user click the "Next" button (either the original or the alternate). Instead, the user is redirected to the first step again. When I stop the experiment, this does not occur. Why would this be happening?

Comment: How is the Data you're capturing for the Customer's info captured, ie are you using Session Cookies etc.?

Comment: On the original, we just pass the data variables via form post. The alternate, we store the data in a session object.

Comment: Are you passing the session object and decoding it on the next page?

Comment: The session is stored in the server memory, so yes we are.